# title does not work with decodeURIComponent and space

Tags: javascript, title, space, decodeuricomponent

I am trying to write with javasctipt line of code, but decodeURIComponent ignore everything after %20 (space). How to solve this?

```
$(".intome").append($('<img title=' + decodeURIComponent(filename) + ' src=' + dir + ' />'));
```

Instead of:

```
<img title:"some text" src="img.png">
```

I am geting this:

```
<img title:"some" text src="img.png">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emnLy1t5/9/

I am an absolute newbie so I would really appreciate any advice. Also I am not native english speaker, so I am sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the output of `decodeURIComponent(filename)` in [quotes](https://jsfiddle.net/emnLy1t5/10/).

```
$(".intome").append(
    $('<img title="' + decodeURIComponent(filename) + '" src=' + dir + ' />')
);
```